# how do I get the errors during make command in pjsip on cygwin resolved

Tags: makefile, cygwin, sip, pjsip

I ran make dep && make clean 
and it went fine.. but when I run make. .i am getting error as below

I am trying to compile pjsip on windows on a cygwin.

I have tried to run the commands several times but could not get answer

==================================================

> $ make for dir in pjlib/build pjlib-util/build pjnath/build
>   third_party/build pjmedia/build pjsip/build pjsip-apps/build ; do \
>           if make  -C $dir all; then \
>               true; \
>           else \
>               exit 1; \
>           fi; \ done make[1]: Entering directory '/home/b60552/pjproject-2.9/pjproject-2.9/pjlib/build' make -f
>   /home/b60552/pjproject-2.9/pjproject-2.9/build/rules.mak APP=PJLIB
>   app=pjlib ../lib/libpj-x86_64-unknown-cygwin.a make[2]: Entering
>   directory '/home/b60552/pjproject-2.9/pjproject-2.9/pjlib/build' mkdir
>   -p output/pjlib-x86_64-unknown-cygwin/ gcc -c -Wall -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -fPIC    -I../include \
>           -o output/pjlib-x86_64-unknown-cygwin/ioqueue_select.o \
>           ../src/pj/ioqueue_select.c In file included from ../src/pj/ioqueue_select.c:41:0: ../src/pj/ioqueue_common_abs.c: In
>   function ‘ioqueue_dispatch_read_event’:
>   ../src/pj/ioqueue_common_abs.c:566:34: error: ‘WSAECONNRESET’
>   undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean
>   ‘OSERR_ECONNRESET’?
>         if (rc == PJ_STATUS_FROM_OS(WSAECONNRESET)) {
>                                     ^ ../include/pj/errno.h:274:34: note: in definition of macro ‘PJ_STATUS_FROM_OS’  #   define
>   PJ_STATUS_FROM_OS(e) (e == 0 ? PJ_SUCCESS : e + PJ_ERRNO_START_SYS)
>                                     ^

=========================================================================

Comment: The symbol WSAECONNRESET is not defined. It looks like the build is trying to build for Windows. Remember that you should consider cygwin to be a strange linux-like system, so follow the build instructions for Linux to build on cygwin. If you want a native windows build, follow the Windows build instructions, including following the Requirements - SDK and Tools on https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows If you intend to build the python extension, that building it under cygwin will only work with cygwin's python.  ...

Comment: ... You must build the extension using the Microsoft tool chain (or equivalent), as specified for WIndows Python extensions, in order to use it with the Windows Python.

Comment: Thanks Doug Henderson, sorry I gave up windows option... I am trying on mac book now...  I also tried doing same on my macbook but make is failing at similar stage for multiple sip versions...  I tried compiling sip 2.0 , sip 1.0 version which I downloaded from GIT hub "svn co https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject.git pj"  .. but there too it fails with error below..rules.mak APP=PORTAUDIO app=libportaudio ../../lib/libportaudio-i386-apple-darwin17.4.0.a
.libportaudio-i386-apple-darwin17.4.0.depend:1:*** missing separator.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [libportaudio] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1